# How to automatically answer interactive cli program (not script) with bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, parted

I've googled this, and almost all I could find is to answer a bash script and this doesn't work for me. The answers I found told to do:

```
echo "yes" | ./script
```

or

```
./script <<< yes
```

or something like that. It didn't work for me. My guess is that's because what I want to do is to auto answer an executable program, not a script. More specifically, I want to auto answer `parted`. Here

```
parted -a optimal /dev/sda mklabel msdos
Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sda will be destroyed and
all data on this disk will be lost. Do you want to continue?
Yes/No? _
```

I try to do

```
echo "yes" | parted -a optimal /dev/sda mklabel msdos
```

and

```
parted -a optimal /dev/sda mklabel msdos <<< yes
```

Both methods didn't work. Those didn't answer `yes` to `parted` prompt.

So, how can I automatically answer that `parted` prompt without using a bash script?

Comment: There is a language for specifically that purpose, to automate interactive programs. it is called "expect" and you can call it from within a bash script.

Comment: Related: [parted script to automate disk partitioning](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-886802-view-next.html?sid=6851c96d655f7b5d4b7c6d7ae29f3912)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `parted`, you can just add the `-s` option:

```
parted -a optimal -s /dev/sda mklabel msdos
```

From the [Trusty `man` page for `parted`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/parted.8.html):

```
[...]
       -s, --script
              never prompts for user intervention
[...]
```

Comment: `never prompts ...` does  it means, yes to all?

Comment: @BagolDaplun Never ask in this case means that the default is used.

Comment: @BagolDaplun As A.B. said `-s` makes `parted` use the default (which is `yes`). Also I corrected the command because here you can't combine options since `-a` needs an argument.